# Any tricks for running large (heavy memory-using) Mocha test suites in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mocha.js

My company has built up a wonderful large (472 and growing) Mocha test suite for our app, and it's incredibly useful ... in Chrome and Firefox.

In IE however the tests break down after 30 or so tests, with an "Error: Out of stack space".  So, my question is ... well really I have two questions, the main one and a back-up:

1) is there any way to just get IE to run the whole suite, perhaps by tweaking some config option somewhere to give it more memory?  I know IE generally sucks at this sort of thing, but if Firefox and Chrome can do it I have to hope there's some way to make IE do it too ...

2) failing that, is there a good way in Mocha to say "run tests 1-25, now run tests 26-50, etc.", or do I just have to use the grep option to try an limit the number of tests run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess I should have spent a bit more time Googling before I came here.  I eventually found this ticket:

https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/502

Which explains that:

1. this is basically bug in Mocha: they're using some sort of mechanism to clear the stack, but that mechanism doesn't work in IE so they need to switch to some other mechanism (and haven't yet, as of 4/25/2013).
2. a (very dirty/hacky, but functional) workaround is to add the following `beforeEach` at the root level of your test suite (so that it applies to all tests):

   beforeEach(function(done){
       window.setTimeout(done, 0);
   });

Comment: BTW, this isn't a totally perfect fix: at about 350 tests in IE starts throwing up pop-ups complaining about a slow script, and asking if I want to stop it, so I have to click "No" a few times to progress.  Even then I only make it to test 414 or so (which is a huge improvement, but not quite the whole suite).  If anyone knows how I can improve IE's memory usage to prevent this pop-up, I'd love to hear it.